# EF 4.1 code first - How to update/delete many to many join table entries automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have 2 entities, let's say, Trip and Activity. The relationship between them is many to many so a join table is created automatically by EF.

Entity Trip attributes:
-Id (PK) Generated by database
-Name
-Description
-Property1
-Property2
-Property3

Entity Activity attributes (this entity contains fixed records -read only-, no records are inserted here on performing inserts):
-Id (PK) Generated by database
-Name
-Description
-Cost

Join table contains 2 columns, that is, the IDs of the above entities, that are primary and foreign keys at the same time.

I have no problems inserting entries which automatically EF creates join table TripActivities and add entries successfully to it. Also entries are added successfully to entity Trip and it leaves unchanged entity Activity.

My problem is on updating entries, for example, - suppose user can modify information related to a trip from the GUI - so I take all the info from this GUI and I perform the following steps to update the existing trip:

```
   Trip trip = Context.Trips.Find(id); // Search for the appropriate trip to update from Id

   trip.Name = ObtainNameFromGUI();
   trip.Description = ObtainDescriptionFromGUI();
   trip.Property1 = ObtainProperty1FromGUI();
   trip.Property2 = ObtainProperty2FromGUI();
   trip.Property3 = ObtainProperty3FromGUI();
   trip.Activities = new List<Activity>();

   // From the GUI user selects from a checkbox list the activities associated to the trip
   // So we read its Ids and from those ids we fetch from database the activities to obtain
   // the info related to each activity selected in the GUI. This is all done inside the
   // below method.
   List<Activity> activities = this.ObtainActivitiesSelectedFromGUI();

   // If no activites selected (=null) I want EF automatically deletes the entries in the
   // joined table for this trip. And of course, if there are activities selected, EF 
   // should update the respectives entries in the joined table for this trip with the new
   // ones.
   if (activites != null)
   {
       activities.ForEach(a =>
                    {
                        trip.Activities.Add(a);
                    });
   }

   context.Trips.Add(trip);
   context.SaveChanges();<br><br>
```

By doing this I want EF updates all the entities related (except Activity as it has fixed entries, must be kept unchanged), that is, Trip and the joined table automatically but it does not work: a new trip is created and more entries in the joined table (The only thing that is working is that entity Activity is kept unchanged as I want).

How to achieve this? I have spent a lot of hours trying to do this but without success...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have removed line:
      context.Trips.Add(trip);

Now the results are:
-Entity Trip is correctly updated, no new records added which is Ok.
-Entity Activity is kept unchanged which is Ok.
-Join table: The old records for current trip being updated are not updated, instead new records are inserted for the current trip which is not correct.

Comment: Finally, it is working. The solution was removing context.Trips.Add(Trip) and doing a clean/rebuild solution. First It was not working well because I think it was taken into account some old DLLs but cleaning and rebuilding entire solution seems to work.

Comment: I am a little curious here. Are you sure your code works for Update scenarios? I would check the Many-To-Many join tables to see if the existing Activity records, which the user un-selected for a Trip during update, are actually removed from the Many-To-Many join table.

Comment: before trip.Activities = new List<Activity>(); I did below:
trip.Activities.Clear(); but why it is necessary? if I assign a new list, this list is empty so it will not be necessary to clear...but it is necessary as I have observed and I do not understand well why.. if you can explain me.... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used a different approach for similar scenario that I faced, which works well with Detached Entities. What I ended up was finding out which entities were added and which ones deleted by comparing GUI(detached entity) values to the database values. Here is the sample code that I have used. The entities in play are **RelayConfig** and **StandardContact** which have many to many relationship

```
    public void Update(RelayConfig relayConfig, List<StandardContact> exposedContacts) {
        RelayConfig dbRelayConfig = context.RelayConfigs.Include(r => r.StandardContacts)
                                           .Where(r => r.Id == relayConfig.Id).SingleOrDefault();
        context.Entry<RelayConfig> (dbRelayConfig).CurrentValues.SetValues(relayConfig);

        List<StandardContact> addedExposedContacts = 
            exposedContacts.Where(c1 => !dbRelayConfig.StandardContacts.Any(c2 => c1.Id == c2.Id)).ToList();
        List<StandardContact> deletedExposedContacts = 
            dbRelayConfig.StandardContacts.Where(c1 => !exposedContacts.Any(c2 => c2.Id == c1.Id)).ToList();

        StandardContact dbExposedContact = null;
        addedExposedContacts.ForEach(exposedContact => {
            dbExposedContact = context.StandardContacts.SingleOrDefault(sc => sc.Id == exposedContact.Id);
            dbRelayConfig.StandardContacts.Add(dbExposedContact);
        });
        deletedExposedContacts.ForEach(exposedContact => { dbRelayConfig.StandardContacts.Remove(exposedContact);});
```

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed sample. It is interesting to know that there are some other good approaches, not only the typical one that I exposed here. A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will use something like this. Assuming that you will get the related objects from the UI and just you are going to update the same in the database, some thing like the following will work.

```
 context.Products.Attach(product);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(product, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(product.ProductDescription, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(product.ProductModel, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

As you may see here, we are setting the EntityState as Modified which hints EF to perform update for the related tables too.

Please post back your queries or any issues that you may encounter in this implementation.

Comment: the problem was in the line: context.Trips.Add(trip); I have removed it and the results are: entity Trip is updated Ok, entity Activity remains unchanged OK, but the problem appears with join table, entries are not updated with the new ones instead the old records are maintained and added new ones in join table... I'll try your approach

Comment: Thanks for this approach. As I have said to @Nirvan it is good to know that there are other approaches that can work.